# Microsoft 365 subscription extra-costs for registering app in Azure Active Directory Admin Center

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am a software developer and I've been working on integrating Microsoft Graph Api in my application to be able to retrieve calendar information for users. For development purposes, I have been using a Microsoft 365 Developer subscription, in which I register my app, by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app. This seems to be working fine with my developer subscription, so after creating a small proof of concept, now I am trying to make a time and cost estimation for this, and I have some doubts about if there are any costs for the client.
Is Azure Active Directory Admin Center available on all Microsoft 365 business plans with the "App registration" option? Or are there any other cost-related aspects I need to take in consideration?
I've searched online and found that there shouldn't be any additional costs, but since I am not really familiar with Microsoft 365 and Azure Active Directory Admin Center other than what I used for my proof of concept, I am not really sure I have the right information.
Maybe there is someone who already implemented this in production and can have a better understanding over this.

Thanks

Comment: I modified my answer,and I'm also learning azure ad.If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer.This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)

Comment: Yup, will do. Thank a lot !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Microsoft 365 subscription extra-costs for Microsoft Graph Api usage

1.There is no extra cost to use the API, it is open source.

> and I have some doubts about if there are any costs for the client.

2.No,it's free.And only microsoft 365 subscription needs to be charged.

3.Yes,all Microsoft 365 subscriptions offer this option.

As @Nishant - MSFT Identity says,Registering apps in Azure AD does not involve any costs and Microsoft 365 E5 developer subscription​ comes with Azure Active Directory(it's free) for building advanced identity and access management solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers . Actually, maybe the title has not a good choice of words(I will update). I know that using The Graph Api in my code doesn't cost, what I am asking is only for the  Azure Active Directory Admin Center, because we need to register our application there and I don't know if all Microsoft 365 subscriptions  offer this option. Also, you said "And only microsoft 365 subscription needs to be charged". Do you mean from developer one to whatever the client has?

Comment: Hello Ana, Registering apps in Azure AD does not involve any costs. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/active-directory/ . Also. Microsoft 365 E5 developer subscription​ comes with Azure Active Directory for building advanced identity and access management solutions

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity Thank you for your clarification!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am a little more relaxed now. The clients have already Micrososft 365 subscription, but each with different ones and  i was thinking maybe some of them will need to change the subscription. I asked the same question on Microsoft Q&A and got this response: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/142453/microsoft-365-subscription-extra-costs-for-microso.html?childToView=143492#answer-143492 . Maybe it will be helpful to others as well

Answer (score 0):

M365 subscription will have an Azure tenant associated with it and hence you can create application for authenticating to AAD using MS Graph.